# Open source program for documentation network and assets in company

Tags: open-source, networking, web, documentation-generator, documentation-viewer

I'm looking for the open source, web program for networks and assets documentation in my company. Which can help with visualization like Visio but working on the web interface. I mean - my employees could use the browser to add new documentation and read in simplest way.
It shouldn't be connected to assets - only for view documentation.
The platform does not matter - it can be a Linux or Windows server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experience with CMDBuild and PHPIpam for all kinds of network and asset management, but I'm sure you can find numerous alternatives if you browse a little bit on https://alternativeto.net/software/phpipam/ and https://alternativeto.net/software/cmdbuild . I hope this helps.

If you're looking for a general documentation web solution, I can recommend DokuWiki and BookStack, but you can find alternatives for those too.